# Нужен плагин для тестирования WooCommerce WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wp-plugin

Доброго времени суток!

Я работаю над созданием темы для WordPress, и чтобы она получилась хорошей, мне необходимо добавить больше данных в базу, чтобы с ними работать. Я уже добавил несколько сотен тестовых товаров, но хочу также придумать что-то с заказами. Пожалуйста, подскажите плагин, который поможет добавить тестовые заказы в базу данных.

Answer (score 0):

Уже сам написал

```
// Получаем массив всех товаров
$products = wc_get_products( array( 'status' => 'publish', 'limit' => -1 ) );

for ( $i = 0; $i < 30; $i++ ) {
   // Создаем новый заказ
   $order = wc_create_order();

   // Генерируем случайное количество продуктов (от 1 до 5)
   $num_products = rand( 1, 5 );

   // Выбираем случайные продукты
   $random_products = array_rand( $products, $num_products );

   // Добавляем каждый случайный продукт в заказ
   foreach ( $random_products as $product_key ) {
      $random_product = $products[ $product_key ];
      $order->add_product( $random_product, 1 );
   }

   // Рассчитываем правильную сумму заказа
   $order->calculate_totals();

   // Устанавливаем статус заказа "completed"
   $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```